# JdbcPagingItemReader Spring batch skipping last element

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-batch

I have a table with this structure:

```
CNMA_CO_PLATFORM_MESSAGE|AUDI_TI_CREATION|FIELD4|OTHER FIELDS
test-jj@2774@20210422112434957@00026129|22/04/21 11:24:34,957000000|11|..
test-jj2@2774@20210422112434957@00026129|22/04/21 11:24:34,957000000|12|..
test-jj3@2774@20210422112434957@00026129|22/04/21 11:24:34,957000000|13|..
```

This combination is the PRIMARY_KEY of the table:
**CNMA_CO_PLATFORM_MESSAGE|AUDI_TI_CREATION**

Well, I have an JdbcPagingItemReader defined like this (Pagesize is 1):

```
@StepScope
@Bean
public JdbcPagingItemReader<PendingNotificationDTO> pendingNotificationReader(
        @Value("#{stepExecution}") StepExecution stepExecution){
    
    final JdbcPagingItemReader<PendingNotificationDTO> reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<>();
    reader.setDataSource(daoDataSource);
    reader.setName("pendingNotificationReader");
    
    //Creamos la Query
    final OraclePagingQueryProvider oraclePagingQueryProvider = new OraclePagingQueryProvider();
    oraclePagingQueryProvider.setSelectClause("SELECT   " + 
            "    cegct.AUDI_TI_CREATION,                "+
            "    CNMA_CO_PLATFORM_MESSAGE,              " + 
            "    OTHERFIELDS...                     ");
    oraclePagingQueryProvider.setFromClause("FROM TABLE1 cegct " + 
            "   JOIN TABLE1 notip ON cegct.field1 = notip.field1 " +
            "   AND notip.field2 = :frSur ");
    oraclePagingQueryProvider.setWhereClause("WHERE "
            + " cegct.field3 = 0 "
            + " AND cegct.field4 in (:notifStatusList) ");
    
    //Indicamos conjunto de campos no repetibles para poder paginar
    Map<String, Order> sortKeys = new HashMap<>();
    sortKeys.put("CNMA_CO_PLATFORM_MESSAGE",                Order.DESCENDING);
    sortKeys.put("AUDI_TI_CREATION",                        Order.DESCENDING);

    oraclePagingQueryProvider.setSortKeys(sortKeys );
    
    reader.setQueryProvider(oraclePagingQueryProvider);
    
    String frSur        = stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().getString(Constants.FM_ROLE_SUR_ZK);
    String notifStatus  = stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().getString(Constants.STATUS_REPORTS);
    
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("frSur", frSur);
    parameters.put("notifStatusList", Arrays.asList(StringUtils.split(notifStatus, ",")));
    reader.setParameterValues(parameters );
    
    Integer initLoaded  = stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().getInt(Constants.RECOVER_PENDING_NOT_COMMIT);
    reader.setPageSize(initLoaded);
    reader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<PendingNotificationDTO>(PendingNotificationDTO.class));
    
    return reader; 
    
}
```

(I hide some irrelevant fields and table names)

Well, I run a test and my 3 records are valid to the select, these are selected one to one by the page size. Anyway, the first chunk-reader generated select my "test-jj3@..." record, my second chunk-reader select "test-jj2@.." and my third chunk-reader doesn't select doesn't recover any record (It should recover last 'test-jj@...' element.

These are the generated sqls (I hide some sensible no relevant fields)

**First chunk, Select 1 register**

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        cegct.AUDI_TI_CREATION                      
        CNMA_CO_PLATFORM_MESSAGE, [otherfields] 
    
    FROM   [FROM] 
    WHERE  [where]
    ORDER BY CNMA_CO_PLATFORM_MESSAGE DESC, AUDI_TI_CREATION DESC

) WHERE ROWNUM <= 1;
```

**Second chunk, Select 1 register (Here, the rownum filter by the sortkeys)**

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        cegct.AUDI_TI_CREATION                      
        CNMA_CO_PLATFORM_MESSAGE, [otherfields] 
    
    FROM   [FROM] 
    WHERE  [where]
    ORDER BY CNMA_CO_PLATFORM_MESSAGE DESC, AUDI_TI_CREATION DESC
) WHERE 
ROWNUM <= 1 AND (
    (CNMA_CO_PLATFORM_MESSAGE < 'test-jj3@2774@20210422112434957@00026129') 
    OR 
    (CNMA_CO_PLATFORM_MESSAGE = 'test-jj3@2774@20210422112434957@00026129' AND AUDI_TI_CREATION < TO_DATE('2021-04-22 11:24:34', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
);
```

**Third chunk, select 0 registers**

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        cegct.AUDI_TI_CREATION                      
        CNMA_CO_PLATFORM_MESSAGE, [otherfields] 
    
    FROM   [FROM] 
    WHERE  [where]
    ORDER BY CNMA_CO_PLATFORM_MESSAGE DESC, AUDI_TI_CREATION DESC
) WHERE 
ROWNUM <= 1 AND (
    (CNMA_CO_PLATFORM_MESSAGE < 'test-jj2@2774@20210422112434957@00026129') 
    OR 
    (CNMA_CO_PLATFORM_MESSAGE = 'test-jj2@2774@20210422112434957@00026129' AND AUDI_TI_CREATION < TO_DATE('2021-04-22 11:24:34', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
);
```

Sorry for my english, I hope you can understand my problem.

Logs for the Prepared SQL Statement

```
    Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT       
    cegct.AUDI_TI_CREATION,             
    CNMA_CO_PLATFORM_MESSAGE,
    OTHERFIELDS...                  
    FROM TABLE1  cegct  
    JOIN TABLE2 notip ON cegct.field1 = notip.field1    
    AND notip.field2  = ? 
    WHERE  cegct.field3  = 0  
    AND cegct.field4  in (?, ?, ?) 
    ORDER BY CNMA_CO_PLATFORM_MESSAGE DESC, AUDI_TI_CREATION DESC) WHERE ROWNUM <= 1]
20221116 12:52:43.560 TRACE  org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils [[ # ]] - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [1], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type unknown
20221116 12:52:43.560 TRACE  org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils [[ # ]] - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 2, parameter value [11], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type unknown
20221116 12:52:43.560 TRACE  org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils [[ # ]] - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 3, parameter value [12], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type unknown
20221116 12:52:43.560 TRACE  org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils [[ # ]] - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 4, parameter value [13], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type unknown
```

Comment: Your log shows `WHERE ROWNUM <= 1` which will restrict the output to a single row. What is the log for the later statements that show 0 results? (you probably ought to have included those logs from the start because they are very relevant to debugging the issue.)

Answer (score 1):

A bind variable is a single value; therefore when you use:

```sql
AND cegct.field4 in (:notifStatusList)
```

Then `:notifStatusList` is a single string and is **NOT** a list of values and you effectively doing the same as:

```sql
AND cegct.field4 = :notifStatusList
```

If the bind variable `:notifStatusList` is a single value then it will work; however, when you try to pass in multiple values then it will not match those multiple values but will try to match `field4` to the entire delimited list (which fails and will filter out all the rows).

---

If you want to pass a delimited string then use:

```sql
AND ',' || :notifStatusList || ',' LIKE '%,' || cegct.field4 || ',%'
```

Alternatively, pass the values as an array (rather than a delimited string) into an Oracle collection and then test to see if it is in that collection.

Comment: In notifStatusList, I am sending an ArrayList (11,12,13). This is a status Id. Each one of the registers of the table have distinct values (I updated original post), and looks like value 12 and 13 are selected. If I change the order of the numers (13,12,11) in the initial string works on the same way. I think problems is in the sortKey because the first field is VARCHAR but I can't guess why. Thanks for your time @MT0

Comment: @JuniorGuy Regardless of what you are doing on the Java-side; in the database, a bind variable is only ever a singular value so the main focus of the answer still holds. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tzJUsfGX)

Comment: Maybe I don't understand you. I added the Statement field conversion to the original post. I can see how the sql driver convert my ArrayList in (?,?,?) and bind the values correctly in each place.

Comment: @JuniorGuy I don't have access to your database driver so if your driver is pre-parsing the SQL and amending it then you are going to get different behaviour to the expected behaviour if that SQL was sent directly to the database.